# Is the change in y as x changes by additional unit given by $\frac {dy} {dx} $

Tags: calculus

I'm currently using RD Sharma to study derivatives. There is a paragraph where I'm stuck right now which is as follows :

"The meaning of the term "rate of change of y with respect to x" is that if x is increased by an additional unit the change in y is given by $\frac {dy} {dx} $.For example, the rate of change of displacement of a particle is defined as its velocity, so if we say that a particle is moving with the velocity v km/hr then it means that when time is increased by one hour the displacement changes by v km. "

Can somebody explain to me what an additional unit means here . Also please explain what this paragraph means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative, when interpreted as velocity, represents what is called *instant* velocity; that is, the velocity you have right now, which might not be the same velocity that you'll see in three minutes or in two seconds (roughly, you can think of instant velocity as the number that is shown in your car's velocimeter).

But to calculate the instant velocity, you start by the more intuitive notion of mean velocity. If $x(t)$ is position as a function of the time $t$, the mean velocity between time $t_0$ and time $t_1$ is the distance you traveled (which is $x(t_1)-x(t_0)$ over the elapsed time ($t_1-t_0$). That is, the mean velocity is
$$v_{t_0,t_1}=\frac{x(t_1)-x(t_0)}{t_1-t_0}.$$

This is also expressed as $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$, where the Greek uppercase letter *Delta* ($\Delta$) stands for *variation*.

Now, if you want to know what the velocity at $t_0$ is, you can get better approximations by taking maybe not an hour, but a minute of time as $t_1-t_0$. Or maybe even better, a second, or a tenth of a second, an so on. Ideally, you would want to take $t_1$ as close to $t_0$ as possible. And that is formalized by the notion of limit: you take $t_1\to t_0$. Then the instant velocity is defined as
$$v(t_0)=\lim_{t_1\to t_0} \frac{x(t_1)-x(t_0)}{t_1-t_0},$$
or if you just say $t$ instead of $t_1$,
$$v(t_0)=\lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{x(t)-x(t_0)}{t-t_0}.$$
Sometimes this is represented as $\frac{d x}{d t}$, where the $d$ represents an infinitesimal variation.

In a more general setting, if $x(t)$ is any function $x$ of $t$, not necessarily position in function of time, the limit
$$\lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{x(t)-x(t_0)}{t-t_0}$$
is called *derivative* of $x$ at $t_0$, and is represented by $x'(t_0)$.

Regarding the notion that $x'(t_0)$ or $\frac{dx}{dt}$ represents how much $x$ varies when you increase $t$ by one unit, that is not exactly true: is just an approximation, which works better, the smaller the increase on $t$ is. Actually, in general you have that
$$\Delta x \approx x'(t_0)\cdot \Delta t,$$
and the claim in the book corresponds only to the case where $\Delta t=1$.

Let's see that the approximation gets better the smaller $\Delta t$ is.

For simplicity, take $x(t)=t^2$ and $t_0=1$ (you can check that then $x'(1)=2$). Consider different values for $t_1$:

- if $t_1=3$, then $\Delta t= 3-1=2$. The approximation for $\Delta x$ gives $$x'(1)\cdot \Delta t=2 \cdot 2 = 4,$$
  but the actual value is $$\Delta x=x(3)-x(1)=3^2-1^2=8.$$
- if $t_1=2$, then $\Delta t= 2-1=1$. The approximation for $\Delta x$ gives $$x'(1)\cdot \Delta t=2 \cdot 1 = 2,$$
  but the actual value is $$\Delta x=x(2)-x(1)=2^2-1^2=3.$$
- if $t_1=1.5$, then $\Delta t= 1.5-1=.5$. The approximation for $\Delta x$ gives $$x'(1)\cdot \Delta t=2 \cdot .5 = 1,$$
  but the actual value is $$\Delta x=x(1.5)-x(1)=1.5^2-1^2=1.25.$$
- if $t_1=1.1$, then $\Delta t= 1.1-1=.1$. The approximation for $\Delta x$ gives $$x'(1)\cdot \Delta t=2 \cdot .1 = .2,$$
  but the actual value is $$\Delta x=x(1.1)-x(1)=1.1^2-1^2=.21.$$
- and if $t_1=1.01$, then $\Delta t= 1.01-1=.01$. The approximation for $\Delta x$ gives $$x'(1)\cdot \Delta t=2 \cdot .01 = .02,$$
  but the actual value is $$\Delta x=x(1.01)-x(1)=1.01^2-1^2=.0201.$$

If you keep taking values of $t_1$ closer and closer to $1$, the approximation gets better and better. But in every case, it's just an approximation; and you can see in fact that for $t=1$, the approximation is not necessarily that good (the real value is $3$, but the derivative is $2$, that approximation is off by one third of the real value).

Answer (score 0):

If $x=7$ (for example), increasing $x$ by an additional unit means $x$ is increased to $7+1=8$. That said, $dy\over dx$ is an “instantaneous” rate of change involving a limit. So while it’s true that if a particle is moving with (constant) velocity $v$ km/hr, its position changes by $v$ units when one hour of time passes, the derivative $dy\over dx$ makes sense even when $y$ is not changing at a constant rate.

If you are driving a car on a straight road, and $y$ is the distance from your starting point and $x$ is the number of hours passed since you set out, $dy\over dx$ is the speed shown on your speedometer. If your speedometer reads $40$ km/hr, you will be $40$ km further down the road in an hour if you maintain that constant speed, but if your speed is not constant, you can’t determine where you’ll be in an hour just be knowing your speed right at one moment.